# Check out a Page Layout to update programatically

Tags: 2010, publishing, page-layout

In a `FeatureActivated` event, I am trying to update the associated content type for a Page Layout. I am running in to issues though with the associated ASPX page not being checked out. Here's my code:

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    SPSite site = (SPSite)properties.Feature.Parent;
    if (PublishingSite.IsPublishingSite(site))
    {
        PublishingSite pubSite = new PublishingSite(site);

        SPContentType ct = site.RootWeb.ContentTypes["Custom Page"];

        string layoutURL = site.ServerRelativeUrl + "_catalogs/masterpage/" + pageLayoutName;
        PageLayout layout = pubSite.PageLayouts[layoutURL];
        layout.AssociatedContentType = ct;
        layout.Update();
    }
}
```

I've tried

```
PageLayout layout = pubSite.PageLayouts[layoutURL];
PublishingPage ppLayout = PublishingPage.GetPublishingPage(layout.ListItem);
ppLayout.CheckOut();
layout.AssociatedContentType = ct;
layout.Update();
ppLayout.CheckIn("Associated CT updated");
```

but this errors out with `Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Invalid SPListItem. The SPListItem provided is not compatible with a Publishing Page.`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do ListItem.CheckOut (for the list item represented by the page layout), rather than trying to check out the page object.

Comment: Thanks James! Right after I posted, another google search lead me to `layout.ListItem.CheckOut();`. I'll accept your answer in 6 minutes!

Comment: No worries, make sure you remember to Publish the item if you need to, too!